# A problem with the Blogger JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, blogger

I have a code that fetches the categorized posts, but the code when adding 150 posts or above is slow to fetch posts. This is the code

```
    if(-1 < e.indexOf("://")) return (-1 < e.indexOf("://www.") ? e.split("://www.") : e.split("://"))[1].split(".")[0]
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($(".emped-tv .views"), function(e, t) {
        var a = $(this),
            i = new Firebase("https://episode-viewer.firebaseIO.com/pages/id/" + a.attr("data-id"));
        i.once("value", function(e) {
            var t = e.val(),
                e = !1;
            null == t && ((t = {
                value: 0
            }).url = window.location.href, t.id = a.attr("data-id"), e = !0), a.html('<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + t.value), t.value++, "/" != window.location.pathname && (e ? i.set(t) : i.child("value").set(t.value))
        })
    }), $(".episodes-get").each(function() {
        for(var e = $(this).find(".server-get i"), t = "", a = "", i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            var s, n, o = e[i].textContent,
                r = o.split("*");
            r[1] ? (s = r[1], n = r[0], 0) : (s = i + 1, n = o);
            o = smart_domain(n);
            null == o && (o = "سيرفر مشاهدة"), 0 == i ? (t += '<a class="server-link active waves-effect waves-light" href="' + n + '" target="abdoutech">' + o + '<span class="server-num">' + s + '<i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></a>', a += '<iframe allowfullscreen="" class="embed-item" frameborder="0" height="1080" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="abdoutech" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" width="1920"></iframe>') : t += '<a class="server-link waves-effect waves-light" href="' + n + '" target="abdoutech">' + o + '<span class="server-num">' + s + '<i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></a>'
        }
        $(".embed-responsive").append(a), $("#servers-content").html(t), $(".embed-responsive .play").click(function() {
            $(".embed-item").attr("src", $(".server-link.active").attr("href")), $(this).remove()
        }), $(".server-link").click(function() {
            $(".server-link").removeClass("active"), $(this).addClass("active")
        }), $(".tabs-content button").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = $(this),
                e = $(this).data("content");
            $(".tabs-content button,.content-div").removeClass("active"), t.toggleClass("active"), $("#" + e).toggleClass("active")
        });
        for(var l = $(this).find(".download-get i"), c = "", i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            var d, f, v = l[i].textContent,
                p = v.split("*"),
                h = "";
            p[1] ? (f = d = p[1], h = smart_domain(m = p[0])) : (d = "", h = smart_domain(m = v), f = "fa fa-download");
            var m = encode_be64(m, $(".home-anime").text(), $(this).attr("number-episode"));
            c += l ? '<a class="waves-effect waves-light" href="' + m + '" target="_blank"><span class="icon-M ' + f + '">' + d + "</span> " + h + "</a>" : "لايوجد روابط تحميل"
        }
        $("#download-content").html('<div class="outer-download">' + c + "</div>");
        var u = $(".home-anime").text(),
            g = document.location.origin + u;
        $.get(g, function(e) {
            var t = $(e).find(".info-post .rating").text();
            $(".emped-tv .details .info h3.rat").html(t + "/10");
            t = $(e).find(".info-post .date").text();
            $(".emped-tv .details .info h3.release").html(t);
            t = $(e).find(".main-posts .post-outer .thumb img").attr("src"), e = $(e).find(".titlepost").text();
            $(".emped-tv .info-container a.cover").attr("href", g).html('<img alt="' + e + '" class="cover" src="' + t + '">'), $(".emped-tv .details .info h1").html('<a title="' + e + '"  href="' + g + '">' + e + "</a>")
        }, "html"), $(".info-container").removeClass("hide")
    }), $("[name-anime]").each(function() {
        var m = $("#episodes-content"),
            e = $(this).attr("name-anime");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + idblogger + "/posts/default/-/" + e + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + numposts,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(e) {
                var t = "",
                    a = "";
                if(e.feed.entry) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                        for(var s = 0; s < e.feed.entry[i].link.length; s++)
                            if("alternate" == e.feed.entry[i].link[s].rel) {
                                var n = e.feed.entry[i].link[s].href;
                                break
                            } var o, r, l = e.feed.entry[i].title.$t,
                            c = e.feed.entry[i].content.$t,
                            d = $(c).find(".episodes-get").attr("number-episode"),
                            f = "";
                        d && (o = d.split("."), c = d.split("-"), o[1] || (c[1] ? (d = c[0], f = " - " + c[1]) : d = (d = d.match(/\d/g)).join(""))), r = d ? " الحلقة : " + d + f : (r = l, ""), t += n == $($("html").html()).filter('meta[property="og:url"]').attr("content") ? '<a data-position="' + d + '" class="active waves-effect"  href="' + n + '" ><i  class="fa fa-pause"></i> ' + r + "</a>" : '<a data-position="' + d + '" class="waves-effect"  href="' + n + '" ><i  class="fa fa-play-circle"></i> ' + r + "</a>", a += '<option data-position="' + d + '" value="' + n + '">' + r + "</option>"
                    }
                    m.html('<div class="episodes-list">' + t + "</div>"), m.append('<select class="ep-select" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">' + a + "</select>"), $(".episodes-list a").sort(function(e, t) {
                        return $(t).data("position") > $(e).data("position") ? 1 : -1
                    }).appendTo(".episodes-list"), $(".ep-select option").sort(function(e, t) {
                        return $(t).data("position") > $(e).data("position") ? 1 : -1
                    }).appendTo(".ep-select");
                    var v = $(".episodes-get").attr("number-episode");
                    $('option[data-position="' + v + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
                    var p = $("option[value*='" + location.pathname + "']"),
                        h = (p.text(), p.next().attr("value")),
                        v = p.prev().attr("value"),
                        p = $(".episodesfastReach"),
                        v = (h ? '<li ><a class="waves-effect"  href="' + h + '">الحلقة السابقة</a></li>' : "") + (v ? '<li ><a class="waves-effect"  href="' + v + '">الحلقة التالية</a></li>' : "");
                    $(p).html(v)
                } else m.html('<div class="box-error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="info-error"></div></div>')
            }
        })
    })
});
```

But I saw a blogger site that brings the classified posts in another way, as it brings 150 posts, and when you go down to the last post, it downloads 150 others.

This is the code for that site that you saw

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: get,
        dataType: jsonp,
        success: function(responce) {
            fn(responce, type);
        }
    });
}

function lazy(fn, done, err, modules) {
    var document;
    var _0xE6BD = err[2][3];
    if(done.scrollTop() + done.innerHeight() >= done[0].scrollHeight && !modules && $(".ep").length < _0xE6BD) {
        document = true; <
        div class = 'lds-ring' > < div > < /div><div></div > < div > < /div><div></div > < /div>;
        load($(".ae-title .loader"), document, < div class = 'lds-ring' > < div > < /div><div></div > < div > < /div><div></div > < /div>);
            fn(err); modules = true; document = false;
        }
    }

    function load(ast, document, name) {
        if(document) {
            ast.append(name);
        } else {
            ast.html("");
        }
    }

    function np(session, lib, end) {
        var THREAD_STARTED = [];
        var cb = 0;
        for(; cb < parseInt(end / 150) + 1; cb++) {
            var id = si(cb);
            ajax(/feeds/posts /
                default / -/ + lib + ?alt=json-in-script&max-results=150&start-index= + id, json_to_np, [THREAD_STARTED]);
            }
            links_ready(THREAD_STARTED, end, append_np, [THREAD_STARTED, window.location.href, session]);
        }

        function links_ready(type, done, error, callback) {
            if(type.length < done) {
                setTimeout(links_ready, 1e3, type, done, error, callback);
            } else {
                error(callback);
            }
        }

        function append_np(right) {
            var [typeR, cardR, nameR] = right;
            var s3 = typeR.indexOf(cardR);
            var managementcommandsdns = 0 == s3 ? : < div class = 'next' > < span > الحلقة التالية < /span><a href=' + typeR[s3 - 1] + '><i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i > < /a></div > ;
            var siteName = s3 + 1 == typeR.length ? : < div class = 'previous' > < span > الحلقة السابقة < /span><a href=' + typeR[s3 + 1] + '><i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i > < /a></div > ;
            nameR.append(managementcommandsdns + siteName);
        }

        function json_to_np(globalComponentsContext, componentStack) {
            var data;
            var PL$13 = globalComponentsContext.feed.entry;
            var command_codes = componentStack[0];
            if(void 0 !== PL$13) {
                var PL$17 = 0;
                for(; PL$17 < PL$13.length; PL$17++) {
                    var signedTransactionsCounter = PL$13[PL$17].link.length - 1;
                    for(; 0 <= signedTransactionsCounter; signedTransactionsCounter--) {
                        if(alternate == PL$13[PL$17].link[signedTransactionsCounter].rel) {
                            data = PL$13[PL$17].link[signedTransactionsCounter].href;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    command_codes.push(data);
                }
            }
        }

        function json_to_episodes(enumValueDeclaration, parameters) {
            var i;
            var sprite;
            var _0xE6A1;
            var PL$13 = enumValueDeclaration.feed.entry;
            var GET_AUTH_URL_TIMEOUT = ;
            var [type, timestamp, totalSecondsToStayOpen, inhibitorObjectPaths, pkg] = parameters;
            var document = true;
            if(void 0 !== PL$13) {
                var PL$17 = 0;
                for(; PL$17 < PL$13.length; PL$17++) {
                    var signedTransactionsCounter = 0;
                    for(; signedTransactionsCounter < PL$13[PL$17].link.length; signedTransactionsCounter++) {
                        if(alternate == PL$13[PL$17].link[signedTransactionsCounter].rel) {
                            _0xE6A1 = PL$13[PL$17].link[signedTransactionsCounter].href;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    i = PL$13[PL$17].content.$t;
                    PL$13[PL$17].title.$t.match(/\u0627\u0644\u062d\u0644\u0642\u0629\s\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
                    GET_AUTH_URL_TIMEOUT = GET_AUTH_URL_TIMEOUT + ( < div class = 'ep' > < a href = ' + _0xE6A1 + ' > +( != (sprite = get_element(i, type)) ? sprite : الحلقة + (inhibitorObjectPaths - (PL$17 + totalSecondsToStayOpen) + 1)) + < /a></div > );
                }
                $(timestamp).find(".eps").append(GET_AUTH_URL_TIMEOUT);
                document = false;
                load(timestamp.find(".ae-title .loader"), document, pkg);
            }
        }

        function get_element(i, name) {
            var flags;
            var regex = ;
            i = < div > +i + < /div>;
            var template = 0;
            for(; template < name.length; template++) {
                regex = regex + (flags = null != (flags = $(i).find(name[template]).html()) ? flags : );
            }
            return regex;
        }

        function get_episodes(layoutItems) {
            var [inputElement, floatLabelOffsetLeft, success] = layoutItems;
            ajax(/feeds/posts /
                default / -/ + floatLabelOffsetLeft + ?alt=json-in-script&max-results=150&start-index= + inputElement, json_to_episodes, success);
            }

            function si(name) {
                return start_ind = 150 * name + 1, start_ind;
            }

            function forward(name, res) {
                var DLF = name.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
                var args = si(0);
                var pkg = < div class = 'lds-ring' > < div > < /div><div></div > < div > < /div><div></div > < /div>;
                var [chain_from, label, chain_memo_sender, chain_propose_account] = res;
                if(load(container.find(".ae-title .loader"), true, pkg), get_episodes([args, chain_from, [chain_propose_account, label, args, DLF, pkg]]), np($("#select-chapter .np"), chain_from, DLF), DLF > 150) {
                    var cb = 1;
                    for(; cb < parseInt(DLF / 150) + 1; cb++) {
                        args = si(cb);
                        $(label).find(".eps").on(scroll, function() {
                            lazy(get_episodes, $(label).find(".eps"), [args, chain_from, [chain_propose_account, label, args, DLF, pkg]], executed = false);
                        });
                        executed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            var anime = $(".anname").attr("data-anime");
            var episode = $(".post-title").text();
            var container = $("#select-chapter");
            var url = /feeds/posts /
                default / -/ + anime + ?alt=json-in-script&max-results=0;
            var go = ajax(url, forward, [anime, container, episode, [.nofe, .noff]]);
```

I want to convert my code to make it like its code

Comment: I want help from here

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment this solution, but unfortunately could not.

Add a read more (jump link) in every post, then it will load as its supposed to.